# Call to function from page in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a HTML page with divs in JQ Mobile.

How can I call to JS function only if the user is in the page I denfied? 

For example:

```
<!-- update page -->
<div data-role="page" id="update">

    <div data-role="header">
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ShowUsers();
        </script>
    </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>© SpicyCanada 2016</h1>
        </div>

</div>

<!-- menu manager page -->
<div data-role="page" id="menuManager">

    <div data-role="header">
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ShowMenu();
        </script>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>

</div>
```

if I want to call "ShowUsers" only if the user in "Update" page and call to "ShowMenu" only if the user in "Menu Manager" page, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1) First, identify the correct `div` with:

```
var $page = document.querySelector('div[data-role="page"]');
```

2) Then, check if the `id` of the `div` is `menuManager`:

```
if ($page.id === 'menuManager') {

[... CONDITIONAL CODE HERE...]

}
```

Comment: This solution always takes the id of the first "div[data-role="page"]" in the page. It does not work.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with how jQuery Mobile works but your comment above suggests that jQM "pages" are actually divs within a single parent document (which helps me better understand the mark-up layout in your question)  - is that right?